# Breadboarding: pins connection

Tags: gpio

I have bought a raspberry pi some time ago, and I have been written some code, but now I need to take use of the breadboarding material. I don't really understand how and where should I connect a device once I have my breadboard joined to my raspberry pi. Some people provide the needed wiring, but I suppose this can be changeable. So how do I know how to connect them and how to read the data from them correctly? Even though some devices already include the appropriate drivers.
I have read something about the pin position (like an id). I think that's the point.

Comment: What component are you trying to connect? What have you tried, Have you looked at tutorials for the pi. @ Adafruit.com - https://learn.adafruit.com/category/raspberry-pi? It is unclear exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @SteveRobillard anything in general, something similar to the answer i got. But applied to each of the breadboard holes. How do they correspond with the pins of the RPI?

Comment: Might I suggest doing a Google search for breadboard basics or how to use a breadboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GPIO pins are laid out as such:

[image: rpi GPIO Lay out]

obviously pin one and 2 provide power to a device.
pins 3 and 5 are I<sup>2</sup>C pins. 
The DNC pins (pin 4, 9, 14, 17, 20) are Do not Connect pins and could be used as ground. (on model B gpio pins 4 is 5v and 17  is 3.3v).

The UART pins(8,10) are Universal Async reciever transmiter (txd is transmit, rxd is recieve)

pins 19, 21,23,24,26 are all SPI pins. MOSI(19) is Master out Slave in; MISO is Master in Slave out SCLK is Serial Clock (output from master).CE is chip enable(also called CS or SS). I am pretty sure the remaining pins are simply high/low pins (not 100% sure as I use predominantly the SPI interface).

Comment: thank you. That was very helpful, so where should I place my chip in the breadboard to fit the correct pin? In other words, what holes of the breadboard correspond to each of the pins?

Comment: That is up to you to decide. There is no one to one correspondence between the gpio pins and the holes on the breadboard. without knowing what chip you are trying to interface we can't really help, but in general you place the chip so that it straddles the channel in the center of the breadboard. See my previous comment regarding Googling breadboard basics. Also if you look at the adafruit site I linked to above they give very detailed instructions on breadboarding projects for the Pi.

Comment: Well if you connect jumper wires from the pi to the bread board, any of the connections in that row should be connected to the pin. refer to http://yourduino.com/Photos/BreadBoard-1.jpg to see how breadboards connect how ever I would refrain from connecting chips directly to the Pins as this may cause the GPIO pins to become damaged. There are several techniques you could implement to prevent this.

Comment: thank you rady and @SteveRobillard. That photo was the key. And steve, from the google search it's a bit difficult to understand it, it's better if you explain it to me ☺️.I have a cobbler to connect the breadboard with the raspberry, I would solder them to the gpio pins anyway because the raspberry is just destined to do that function so i won't have to disconnect it from there. The cobbler it's very helpful though.